# What is ngc module codegen

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am having the error

```
$ node node_modules/.bin/ngc --project foo
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './codegen'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/paul/lucid/main2/cake/node_modules/.bin/ngc:5:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

I'm trying to decrypt this error. What is `./codegen` and what path is node trying to read it from?

Comment: I'm having the same problem... did you find a solution or where this error comes from?